How to filter a time series after applying aggregation in PromQL?
I have a promQL expression like this- sum(metric_1) by (label_1). Now, I want to filter out the output of the expression using another label label_2. Something like this- (sum(metric_1) by (label_1, label_2)){label_2="some_value"}. But, this is not working and is giving a parse error. How can I achieve this?

Result of aggregation in your example doesn't have label2, so it's not entirely clear what you are trying to do.

@markalex thanks for pointing this out. I have updated the question. I think for a simple expression I can filter before the aggregation, but, for more complex expressions, how can I apply the filter at the end?

Example in your edit is in fact handled by filtering before aggregation. I can get example for more complex query of the top of my head. But if we are talking about filtering based on synthetic labels introduced by label_replace, you might use and on(label) construction.

wouldn't that require another time series after the and on(label)?

A way I've seen this operation done previously is by using recording rules. You can build out a new metric with your aggregated query along with any labels you'd like to select from.

I understand that that is an option. However, my question focuses on achieving a similar output using a single PromQL expression.

Prometheus doesn't support label-based post-filtering of query results, so all the label-based filtering must be performed at label filters in curly braces before applying any PromQL function. For example, if the sum of metric_1 time series with the label_2="value_2" label must be calculated, then the following query can be used:
sum(metric_1{label_2="value_2"}) by (label_1)

P.S. If additional post-filtering on labels is needed after applying some PromQL function such as label_replace, then the following MetricsQL functions can be used at VictoriaMetrics - Prometheus-like monitoring solution with PromQL support:

label_match
label_mismatch

(I'm the core developer of VictoriaMetrics).
